# Batch conversion of PVR to JPEG (or similar)

Tags: image-conversion

(This question was originally posted at [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/batch-conversion-of-pvr-to-jpeg-or-similar), but it was suggested that this may be a more appropriate place for it)

The command line [PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) works very well for getting textures into a PVR format, but I need a way of going the opposite directions. Does anyone know of a good command line tool (or GUI with a batch mode) that will convert a PowerVR texture to a more common image format (like JPEG or PNG?)

Answer (score 2):

Inside one of the folders of [PVRTexTool](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/) you find PVRTexToolCLI.exe, that is the command-line version of it. You can use a batch command on it like this:

```
for %f in (*.pvr) do PVRTexToolCLI.exe -i "%f" -d -f r8g8b8a8
```

Comment: Use %%f when using the above in batch-files

Answer (score 0):

In the PVRTexTool GUI at least, you can go to Edit > Save MIP-Level to output it in one of the regular image formats.

Comment: Yes, which I have been doing. But I'm also looking at converting ~1000 PVR textures, and that's an awful lot of clicking...